# Geodesic equation — alternative form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

From Thomas Moore A General Relativity Workbook I have the geodesic equation as,

$$ 0=\frac{d}{d \tau} (g_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\beta}{d \tau}) - \frac{1}{2} \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d \tau} \frac{dx^\nu}{d \tau} $$

as well as

$$ 0= \frac{d^2 x^\gamma}{d \tau^2}  + g^{\gamma\alpha} (\partial_\mu g_{\alpha\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}) \frac{dx^\mu}{d \tau} \frac{dx^\nu}{d \tau}.
$$

However, I have a friend writing down the geodesic equation as

$$ 0=g_{\alpha j}\frac{d^2x^j}{d \tau^2} + (\partial_i g_{\alpha j}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\alpha g_{ij}) \frac{dx^j}{d \tau} \frac{dx^i}{d \tau}.
$$

and getting the right answers.

And I losing my mind? Is that equation the geodesic equation?!

Comment: In what way do you believe your friend's equation differs from the second equation from your textbook?

Comment: Wow, I am lossing my mind. A hint for anyone who reads this in the future, $g_{ab}g^{ab} = \delta^{ab}$. Thank you J. Murray!

Comment: Actually $g_{ab}g^{ab}=\delta^a_a = d$, where $d$ is the dimension of your spacetime.  You meant to write $g_{ab} g^{bc} = \delta_a^c$.   But no worries, it happens ;)

Comment: Bahaha *facepalm yes of course!